# Configuring Spring Security without the plugin web.xml problems

Tags: tomcat, grails, spring-security

I'm currently building a Grails 1.3.5 app.  It uses an existing model layer (shared code - no GORM) and I've successfully configured the tomcat jndi connections for it in conf/spring/resources.xml and all is working well.  However I'm having problems when I try and configure Spring security.  I'm NOT using the spring security plugin because I want to use the xml security config from another project we already have running.  This uses Spring 3 security. I've followed the following steps on various blogs:

- Ran 'grails install-templates'

I added the following to the templates/war/web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring Security Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>filterChainProxy</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring Security Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

- I added my security beans to the
  conf/spring directory and have
  validated them.
- I've copied the spring security jar
  files over to the grails lib
  directory.  Version 3.0.2

When I run 'grails run-app' I get a very strange exception with the web.xml:

```
2010-11-26 12:16:02,512 INFO  [startup.ContextConfig] No default web.xml
2010-11-26 12:16:02,518 ERROR [digester.Digester] End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:925)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name hiddenHttpMethod
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:925)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:193)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1140)
    ... 437 more
```

I've also copied the filter code from other blogs that suggest:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But I still get the same problem.

Does anyone have any advice about what I should try next?  The annoying thing is that I had this all working on an older version of Grails (1.1.1) with version 2 of the security modules but now I'm getting problems.

Comment: By the way I've managed to get the same app working using Spring Security 2.0.4.  I've configured everything in the same way with the exception of the slightly different security bean definitions. Security v3 uses: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy whereas v2 uses: org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.  I get past the above error and get 'No bean named 'Spring Security Filter Chain Proxy' is defined'.  It's defined in config/spring/ but not in web-app/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml. Seems wrong to put bean defs in there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working a while back but it took a different setup in 1.3 than what worked in 1.2. I found I could only access external XML files by adding them to the contextConfigLocation context-param in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
      /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
   </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Other than that the configuration was the same as for a non-Grails app. You probably also need the config jar.

Also, rather than copying jars to your lib directory you should use the IVy config in BuildConfig.groovy so you only have one copy of each jar on your machine. Here's one that should work:

```
grails.project.class.dir = 'target/classes'
grails.project.test.class.dir = 'target/test-classes'
grails.project.test.reports.dir = 'target/test-reports'

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

   inherits 'global'
   log 'warn'

   repositories {
      grailsPlugins()
      grailsHome()
      grailsCentral()
      ebr() // SpringSource  http://www.springsource.com/repository
   }

   dependencies {
      runtime('org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.core:3.0.3.RELEASE') {
         excludes 'com.springsource.org.aopalliance',
                  'com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging',
                  'org.springframework.beans',
                  'org.springframework.context',
                  'org.springframework.core'
      }

      runtime('org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.config:3.0.3.RELEASE')

      runtime('org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:3.0.3.RELEASE') {
         excludes 'com.springsource.javax.servlet',
                  'com.springsource.org.aopalliance',
                  'com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging',
                  'org.springframework.aop',
                  'org.springframework.beans',
                  'org.springframework.context',
                  'org.springframework.core',
                  'org.springframework.web'
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I'm installing the spring-security-core plugin so that I get the security tag libs.  Is this the best way to do it or is there a better way?